# showing update and delete links only to post author in django

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I want to display Update and delete link only to the author of the post in django blog.But `{% if request.user == posts.author %}` on template is throwing an error `Could not parse the remainder: '==posts.author' from 'request.user==posts.author'`.How do i slove this?

**Views.py**

```
def post_detail(request,slug):
    posts=Post.objects.get(slug=slug)
    posts.seen_by=posts.seen_by+1
    posts.save()
    context={'posts':posts}
    return render(request,'blog/post_detail.html',context)
```

**post_detail.html**

```
{% extends 'blog/base.html'%}


{% block content%}
        <a href="{%url 'post-cate' posts.category %}">{{posts.category}}</a>
            <p>{{posts.date_posted}}</p>
        <h1>{{posts.title}}</h1>
        {% if request.user==posts.author %}
        <p><a href="{% url 'post-update' posts.slug %}">Update</a> <a href="{% url 'post-delete' posts.slug %}">Delete</a> </p>
        {% endif%}
            <strong>{{posts.content}}</strong><p>- <a href="{% url 'post-by-user' posts.author %}">{{posts.author}}</a></p>
            Seen:{{posts.seen_by}}
            <hr>
{% endblock content%}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should put spaces around the ***`==`*** symbol,

```
{% if request.user == posts.author %}
                ^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Even if the posts.author and the request.author  are same this condition doesn't run. Why is this so?

Comment: Probably you missed something in your code. This code will work as-is